# Reload PM2 configuration file

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have problems with reloading PM2 configuration file after editing it:

```
{
    "apps": [
        ...
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "script": "foo/index.js",
            "cwd": "foo",
            "watch": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I previously did

```
pm2 restart config.json
```

and

```
pm2 reload config.json
```

and

```
pm2 gracefulReload config.json
```

but they didn't reload the configuration for existing apps (the changes in app config did not apply). The only way that worked for me was:

```
pm2 delete foo
pm2 restart config.json
```

How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As [the reference](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) states, configurations are no longer reloaded:

> Starting PM2 v2.1.X, environnements are immutable by default, that means they will never be updated unless you tell PM2 to do so, to update configurations, you will need to use --update-env options.

So this should be

```
pm2 startOrReload config.js --update-env
```

Comment: Just to update the reference above .. this is where you can find the info 
[--update-env](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/#updating-environment-variables-and-options)

Comment: This worked well for a pm2 config file reload to change arguments passed to the started script of the process I was targeting. Just a quick note I had to use the full path to the configuration file. `pm2` will not find the file unless told specifically where to look for it.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `pm2` for **local development** and have problems with reloading the config you should run:

```
$ pm2 delete ecosystem.config.js
```

This deletes existing services (don't worry, no files will be deleted). Then to reload the configuration run:

```
$ pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

(**Tip:** you may need to replace `ecosystem.config.js` with your config file name)

This is a **very rough** way of reloading, but it's good if you want a clean slate. It's effective to solve some issues, like I had with `node-config` - I was getting `NODE_APP_INSTANCE` warnings even though I added `instance_var` to my ecosystem config.

Comment: does this delete wipe out all the logs for that instance so far?

Answer (score 5):

If you need a COMPLETE PURGE and restart of the configuration:

```bash
pm2 kill                                 # kill ongoing pm2 processes
pm2 flush                                # OPTIONAL if logs need to be removed
pm2 start /path/to/ecosystem.config.js   # load config file
pm2 save                                 # save current process list / save changes after loading config file
```

This can be useful if you keep getting pm2 feedback: `status: errored`.

If you only want to reload i.e. "refresh" the configuration use this:

```
pm2 startOrReload config.js --update-env
```

You should try reload first and if the configuration is still not refreshed, try the complete purge.

Comment: that is pure wrong. u kill all process just to update 1

Comment: The answer mentions "kill ongoing pm2 processes" which means a COMPLETE PURGE. And it does answer the question to "Reload PM2 configuration file".